# Hibernate load/get a reference not a new instance

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

When I load() an object hibernate return me a proxy object and when I get() an object hibernate return me a new instance of this object.

But If I have for example: One Exercise has many Categories and One Category has many Exercises and there are 4 categories that always are same: A, B, C, D

When I get an Exercise with its category, e.g. A and then get other with A too.

Have I two instances of A? Because A is the same for all exercises. How can I share the same reference for all Exercises?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate's Session *ensures* that no duplicated objects are loaded. You'll have several references to the same objects.

If you loaded the same object twice in 2 sessions and then you're trying to save both in a single session, you'll get an exception that would state that there are 2 same object associated with the session.